# removing P texts that doesn't have the text INPUT value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search input and a few DIVs, I want when I write in the input the divs that it's text doesn't have the input's value disappear.

I'm tried this code but it's not working

```html
<div class="opened-sid">

    <input type="text" class="looking">

    <div class='some'>

        <div class="eac-ques">
            <p class="the-qu">first</p>
        </div>

        <div class="eac-ques">
            <p class="the-qu">secont</p>
        </div>

        <div class="eac-ques">
            <p class="the-qu">third</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```jquery
$('.opened-sid .looking').keyup(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        var el = $(this);

        $('.eac-ques .the-qu').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim() === el.trim();
        }).parents('.eac-ques').removeClass('disp-no').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('disp-no');
    });

});
```

Comment: what is the code supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

This is how to `filter` query from your data

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" class="search">
  <div class="output"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(() => {
  $('.search').keyup(function() {
    let lists = ['first', 'fast', 'second', 'send', 'third', 'touch']
    let search = $(this).val();
    query = lists.filter(list => {
      return list.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
    })
    
    $('.output').text(query)
  })
})
</script>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.opened-sid .looking').keyup(function (e) {
  let searchString = $('.looking:first').val();
  $('p.the-qu').hide();
  if (searchString !== '')
    $('p.the-qu:contains("'+ searchString +'")').show();
});
```

Working PEN: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matrixb51/pen/dybeqwp)

Answer (score 0):

The `on('input')` event handler always gets the job done.

```html
<body>
    <div class="opened-sid">
  
        <input type="text" class="looking">

        <div class='some'>

            <div class="eac-ques">
                <p class="the-qu">first</p>
            </div>

            <div class="eac-ques">
                <p class="the-qu">secont</p>
            </div>

            <div class="eac-ques">
                <p class="the-qu">third</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
       integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var target = $('.looking');
            target.on('input', function() {
                $.each($('.the-qu'), function(i, e) {
                    if(!$(e).html().startsWith(target.val().toLowerCase())) {
                        $(e).parent().hide();
                    } else {
                        $(e).parent().show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```